# Automate import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have this to import all modules if they dont exist, the thing is that even if i have them it also behaves has if i dont, what am i doing wrong?

```
listimport=["request","shutil","shutil","styless","time","tkinter","openpyxl","html","datetime","importlib","string",
      "easygui","bs4","webbrowser","glob","tarfile","webbrowser","pathlib","platform","subprocess","tkinterweb",
            "jira","numpy","matplotlib","calendar","sys","math","math","parser","pyautogui","dateutil","xlwt"]
for x_imp in listimport:
    try:
        import x_imp
    except ImportError as e:
        os.system('pip install ' + x_imp)
```

this always tries to install all modules even if they already exist, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a module you do it like this:

```py
import request
```

Using your program you will try to import every **string** like this:

```py
import "request"
```

Because `listimport` contains strings! so you will get an error every time!

You can fix it using `__import__` that do the same thing, but on a **string**:

```py
import os

listimport = ["request","shutil","shutil","styless","time","tkinter","openpyxl","html","datetime","importlib","string",
      "easygui","bs4","webbrowser","glob","tarfile","webbrowser","pathlib","platform","subprocess","tkinterweb",
            "jira","numpy","matplotlib","calendar","sys","math","math","parser","pyautogui","dateutil","xlwt"]

for x_imp in listimport:
    try:
        __import__(x_imp)
    except ImportError as e:
        os.system('pip install ' + x_imp)
```

Comment: thanks, that fix it :)

Comment: i know this is a second question but how can i install os without doing pip install os everythime i run the program in order for this script to work?

Comment: I don’t understand the question, os is installed with python by default…

Comment: it is??but when i compile the program into a portable app will it also send the os?

Comment: Yes it will send the os too.

Answer (score 2):

You are now trying to import a string, for example `import "numpy"`. A simple solution can be to use `exec()`

```py
listimport=["request","shutil","shutil","styless","time","tkinter","openpyxl","html","datetime","importlib","string",
      "easygui","bs4","webbrowser","glob","tarfile","webbrowser","pathlib","platform","subprocess","tkinterweb",
            "jira","numpy","matplotlib","calendar","sys","math","math","parser","pyautogui","dateutil","xlwt"]

for x_imp in listimport:
    try:
        exec('import {}'.format(x_imp))
    except ImportError:
        os.system('pip install ' + x_imp)
```

Comment: thanks:) i know this is a second question but how can i install os without doing pip install os everythime i run the program in order for this script to work?

Comment: The os module is part of the python's standard library and therefore doesn't need `pip install os`. You can therefore safely assume that when python is installed, you can always use the os module.

Comment: thanks, but when i compile to a portable app will it send the os too in case the person that is going to use it dont have python installed?